# How do you generate a regular non-integer sequence in julia?

Tags: julia

How are regular, non-integer sequences generated in julia?

I'm trying to get `0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0`

In MATLAB, I would use

```
0.1:0.1:1
```

And in R

```
seq(0.1, 1, by = 0.1)
```

But I can't find anything except integer sequences in julia (e.g., `1:10`). Searching for "sequence" in the docs only gives me information about how strings are sequences.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original answer is now deprecated. You should use `collect()` to generate a sequence.

```
## In Julia
> collect(0:.1:1)
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.1
 0.2
 0.3
 0.4
 0.5
 0.6
 0.7
 0.8
 0.9
 1.0

## In R
> seq(0, 1, .1)
 [1] 0.0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1.0
```

Comment: What's the difference between collect(0:.1:1) and range(1,length=10,step=0.1) ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, range still doesn't generate the sequence.. you would need to wrap collect() around it

Comment: I disagree. The correct answer is to just use `0:0.1:1`. You don't need `collect`, except in very particular circumstances.

Comment: Definitely agree with @DNF - I've added another answer below laying this out.

Answer (score 15):

Similarly to Matlab, but with the difference that `0.1:0.1:1` defines a `Range`:

```
julia> typeof(0.1:0.1:1)
Range{Float64} (constructor with 3 methods)
```

and thus if an `Array` is needed:

```
julia> [0.1:0.1:1]
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.1
 0.2
 0.3
 0.4
 0.5
 0.6
 0.7
 0.8
 0.9
 1.0
```

Unfortunately, this use of `Range` is only briefly mentioned [at this point of the documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.2/manual/arrays/#indexing).

**Edit:** As mentioned in the comments by @ivarne it is possible to achieve a similar result using linspace:

```
julia> linspace(.1,1,10)
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.1
 0.2
 0.3
 0.4
 0.5
 0.6
 0.7
 0.8
 0.9
 1.0
```

but note that the results are not exactly the same due to rounding differences:

```
julia> linspace(.1,1,10)==[0.1:0.1:1]
false
```

Comment: There is also the linspace function.

Comment: Then is it better to use linspace or collect?

Answer (score 2):

They are generated the same way as in Matlab

```
julia> sequence = 0:.1:1
0.0:0.1:1.0
```

Alternatively, you can use [the `range()` function](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/math/#Base.range), which allows you to specify the length, step size, or both

```
julia> range(0, 1, length = 5)
0.0:0.25:1.0

julia> range(0, 1, step = .01)
0.0:0.01:1.0

julia> range(0, step = .01, length = 5)
0.0:0.01:0.04
```

You can still do all of the thinks you would normally do with a vector, eg indexing

```
julia> sequence[4]
0.3
```

math and stats...

```
julia> sum(sequence)
5.5

julia> using Statistics

julia> mean(sequence)
0.5
```

This will (in most cases) work the same way as a vector, but nothing is actually allocated. It can be comfortable to make the vector, but in most cases you shouldn't (it's less performant). This works because

```
julia> sequence isa AbstractArray
true
```

If you truly need the vector, you can `collect()`, splat (`...`) or use a comprehension:

```
julia> v = collect(sequence)
11-element Array{Float64,1}:
 0.0
 0.1
 0.2
 0.3
 0.4
 0.5
 0.6
 0.7
 0.8
 0.9
 1.0

julia> v == [sequence...] == [x for x in sequence]
true
```